# Dealing with angles in 3D

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, angles

In 2D everything is easier to understand. I'm not enought experienced to join people who say that 3d is the same: you JUST need to add a dimension - THAT adding a dimension is my problem, bacause I can't easily visualize (or draw on paper) the situation I'm dealing with. So please don't say it is the same.

First let's talk of a concrete situation.

**Use case: bounding sphere intersection**

I have two entities colliding with theirs bounding sphere intersecting at a certain point. Let's consider two vectors, the velocity of the first entity `v1` and distance between boundingsphere centers `d`. If I want to get `v1` component along `d` I may want to do

```
V1 * Math.Cos(alpha)
```

with `alpha = Math.Atan2(...)`

**a.** My questions come now. `Math.Atan2(...)` takes 2 arguments, the
    first is the difference between Xs and second is the difference
    between Ys of the two vectors involved. So, since I'm working in 3D
    and not in 2D, should I assume that common practice is to consider a
    pair of dimenstion at time when dealing with angles in 3D? Since I'm
    a bit confused here, can someone tell me what's the best practice to
    follow in this case? (details would be appreciated here).

**b.** Then I have some information I'd like someone to confirm. When my
    double angle value is returned from the `Math.Atan2(...)`, I have my
    angle in radians. I read somewhere that this float value varies
    between `+- Pi`, reasonable. And also that `Math.Atan2(...)` always
    consider the lesser between the 2 angles, which is not important if
    you need to calculate `Cos(angle)` but you must keep it in mind if
    you wants to get the `Sin(angle)`. Is this how things work?

Comment: It's a good rule of thumb that, if you are using trigonometric functions (sin, cos, tan, atan2, etc), you are *probably* doing something wrong. If you are passing the output of atan2 directly into sin or cos (converting to an angle and back), then you are *definitely* doing something wrong. In both 2D and 3D games you should prefer linear algebra approaches, as per Steve H's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an approach that relies heavily on trig (ie. your Atan2) as a means to solve the problem, 3d lends itself to a more linear algebra approach.

```
float v1ComponentAlongD = Vector3.Dot(v1, d); // look ma, no angles
```

Check out the last two paragraphs in Shawns blog here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/02/12/doing-math-in-2d-vs-3d.aspx

So really I would recommend not wanting an answer to your a & b. Instead, get comfortable migrating away from trying to relate every problem to angles and instead relate it all to vector math (mainly the dot product and the cross product).

Generally in 3d, you won't get completely away from angles, but it sure is easier to do 3d when you can lean heavily on linear algebra and less on trig.

Comment: Commentary [imported to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13019/discussion-between-steve-h-and-leggy7).

Comment: Please avoid having extended discussions in comments.